# filter date column mysql

Tags: mysql, date, filter, mysql-error-1064, metabase

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where paid_date between" January1,2021" and "Getdate()"' at line 5. Can someone help me fix my SQL?

```sql
select DATEDIFF(paid_date, cart_shipped_date) Days_till_paid, stat_completed_carts.* 
from stat_completed_carts
where billing_method_id="30"
where paid_date between" January1,2021" and "Getdate()";
```

Comment: You are using the "WHERE" clause twice. Replace the second one with "AND".

Comment: @Manoj-kr Thanks that was helpful, I appreciate it. now I am getting this error                          This may be the answer you’re looking for. If not, try removing or changing your filters to make them less specific.